# C# Sql update database

Tags: c#, sql, phpmyadmin

I'm having `issues updating my database`. I have created an application to take a `customers name, phone, email, their computer details and the services`. I would like to **update** them but I am running into some troubles. The way I inserted data into my database was like this.

```
private void btnCreate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //string connString = "server=localhost;uid=*****;password=********;database=dbomonkworksinfo;";
            MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost;uid=******;password=********;database=dbomonkworksinfo;");
            conn.Open();

 try
            {
                MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("Insert into tserviceinfo (First_Name, Last_Name, Date, Phone, Email, Tech, Brand, Model, OS, Type, PC_Issue) values (?First_Name, ?Last_Name, ?Date, ?Phone, ?Email, ?Tech, ?Brand, ?Model, ?OS, ?Type, ?PC_Issue)", conn);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?First_Name", tbFirstName.Text);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?Last_Name", tbLastName.Text);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?Date", tbDate.Text);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?Phone", tbPhone.Text);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?Email", tbEmail.Text);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?Tech", tbTech.Text);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?Brand", tbBrand.Text);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?Model", tbModel.Text);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?OS", tbOS.Text);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?PC_Issue", tbIssue.Text);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?Services", lvOrdered.Items);

                if (rbDesktop.Checked)
                {
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?Type", "Desktop");
                }
                else if (rbNotebook.Checked)
                {
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?Type", "Notebook");
                }

               /** MySqlCommand command2 = new MySqlCommand("Insert into tpcinfo (Brand, Model, OS, PC_Issue, Services) values (?Brand, ?Model, ?OS, ?PC_Issue, ?Services)", conn);
                command2.Parameters.AddWithValue("?Brand", tbBrand.Text);
                command2.Parameters.AddWithValue("?Model", tbModel.Text);
                command2.Parameters.AddWithValue("?OS", tbOS.Text);
                command2.Parameters.AddWithValue("?PC_Issue", tbIssue.Text);
                command2.Parameters.AddWithValue("?Services", lvOrdered.Items);
                * Changed to only one table. No one besides me sees the behind the program. 
                * **/


                //command2.Parameters.AddWithValue("?type", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = type;
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conn.Close();

                tbFirstName.Clear();
                tbLastName.Clear();
                tbDate.Clear();
                tbEmail.Clear();
                tbBrand.Clear();
                tbIssue.Clear();
                tbTech.Clear();
                tbModel.Clear();
                tbPhone.Clear();
                tbOS.Clear();
                lvOrdered.Items.Clear();
                lblPrice.Text = "$0.00";

            }
            catch (MySqlException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Can't connect to database\n" + ex.ToString());
            }
        }
```

My question is really, `how would I write an update statement?` I have looked on-line, but I have been unable to adapt anything to my needs and I am drawing a blank. I was working on this program pretty constant but I have kind off stopped for a few months and now I am really drawing a blank. Any help would be greatly appreciated it! I am able to view data that is inputted but now updating is the next step! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is as simple as this,

```
UPDATE tserviceinfo 
SET    First_Name = ?First_Name, 
       Last_Name = ?Last_Name, 
       Date = ?Date, 
       Phone = ?Phone, 
       Email = ?Email, 
       Tech = ?Tech, 
       Brand = ?Brand, 
       Model = ?Model, 
       OS = ?OS, 
       Type = ?Type
// WHERE  condition here
```